# Move Image on Button Click in Sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I wanted to move an image on button click. Like when i click on button , image should move from left to right . I was finding the x and y of image but failed to achieve goal. I have also tried with sliderfiled but suckes to change the default image of sliderfiled via sencha touch css. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ext.Anim](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Anim) make an image move. Just define you animation like so

```
anim = Ext.create('Ext.Anim',{
  autoClear: false,
  from:{'left':'0px'}, // You can use CSS3 transforms for better performance
  to: {'left':'100px'},
  delay: 1000,
  duration: 1000
});
```

Then you can [run](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Anim-method-run) this animation on any component. For example, if you have a reference to you image in a controller.

```
anim.run(this.getImage().element);
```

Hope this helps